# Connect to Docker MS SQL Server on Mac OS

Tags: r, sql-server, docker

I have successfully installed Docker version 20.10.24, build 297e128; pulled the MS Server 2019 image (mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest; and restored the WideWorldImporters database. I installed the Microsoft ODBC driver 18 for SQL Server using homebrew. I can connect to and query the database using both Azure Data Studio and VS Code. While it seems that I can connect from RStudio, the schema/databases are all bizarre values and the "tables" are even more strange.

The connection string is

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), 
                      Driver = "ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server", 
                      Server = "localhost", 
                      Database = "WideWorldImporters",
                      uid = "sa",
                      pwd = "SuperSecretPassword",
                      trustservercertificate = "yes")
```

Note: Unless I included the `trustservercertificate` statement, I got an `SSL Provider: [error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed:self-signed certificate]` error.

The "scheme/databases" shown in the Connections tab are `mse`, `md`, `tmd`, and `WdWrdmotr`. A sample of the 590 "tables" are

```
> DBI::dbListTables(con)
  [1] "Cte"                          "Cte_rhv"                      "Cuti"                         "CutisAci"
```

Comment: Is there a question here? The `TrustServerCertificate` behaviour is well-known, [ODBC Driver 18.0 for SQL Server Released](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/odbc-driver-18-0-for-sql-server-released/ba-p/3169228).

Comment: The question is how do I access the database and tables in the Docker environment using R.

Comment: If you've restored the `WideWorldImports-Full.bak` file there should be around 590 tables returned from `dbListTables(con)` - mostly system tables and dynamic management views. In RStudio's Console tab if you type `con` and press enter does it display `Database: WideWorldImporters` or does it report another database? What happens if you type `dbSendStatement(con, "USE WideWorldImporters")` and then try `dbListTables(con)` again?

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations. As you say, the `dbListTables(con)` statement returns a list of approximately 590 tables and the `con` statement returns`Database: WideWorldImporters Microsoft SQL Server Version: 15.00.4312`. The tables,  schema, and data, however, are unrecognizable. For example, the query `SELECT TOP (1) [CityName] FROM [Application].[Cities]` returns a value of "Arnbr" while the values should be "Aaronsburg"

Comment: Interestingly, `len([CityName])` returns 10 though it only displays 5 character. If I consider other city values, RStudio seems to be returning/displaying the  1, 3, 5, 7, etc characters of the string.